# Arduino LCD not turning on?

Tags: arduino, display, arduino-uno, lcd

I am trying to get an **Arduino LCD screen** to display some text. However, despite the wiring being done correctly, the **LCD display** doesn't even turn on when I upload the code, let alone display text. I have also tried connecting a **potentiometer** that would allow me to **change brightness / contrast**, but to no avail.

The compiler shows **no issues** and the code is **uploaded successfuly:**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal screen(12 , 11 , 10 , 9 , 8 , 7 , 6 , 5 , 4 , 3 , 2);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  screen.begin(16 , 2);
  screen.setCursor(0 , 0);
  screen.print("Hello world!");
  screen.setCursor(0 , 1);
  screen.print("Test successful!");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What LCD device is it?

Comment: Maybe you should shown your connection diagram on how you wiring the LCD with the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

> LiquidCrystal screen(12 , 11 , 10 , 9 , 8 , 7 , 6 , 5 , 4 , 3 , 2);

The LCD 16x2 are often setup to operate at 4-bit mode to save the number of GPIO pins required for interfacing with the LCD. For some reason, you seems to want to use 8-bit mode and choose to explicitly set the mode by your class instantiation. In this case, the function prototype according to the library [source code](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal/blob/master/src/LiquidCrystal.cpp#L53-L55) would be:

```
void LiquidCrystal::init(uint8_t fourbitmode, uint8_t rs, uint8_t rw, uint8_t enable,
             uint8_t d0, uint8_t d1, uint8_t d2, uint8_t d3,
             uint8_t d4, uint8_t d5, uint8_t d6, uint8_t d7)
```

Noticed that the first argument in the class instantiation specify whether you'd want to setup the display to operate at 4-bit mode or 8-bit mode, so if you want to use the 8-bit mode, the instantiation should be:

```
LiquidCrystal screen(1, rs_pin, rw_pin, enable, d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7);
```

If you want to use the 4-bit mode, there is an class [overload construct](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal/blob/master/src/LiquidCrystal.cpp#L47-L51) which only requires you to specify 6-pin with

```
LiquidCrystal screen(rs,  enable, d0, d1, d2, d3)
```

It will internally set the `fourbitmode` to 0, and d4-d7 to 0.